# How to get started with creating an R application that is based on / uses JGR?

Tags: java, r

can anyone point me to a good start for developing a JGR dependable R application?
Roughly speaking I want to do something that enhances the JGR menu by some options just like [Deducer (btw now available with ggplot2!!)](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/08/ggplot2-plot-builder-is-now-available-on-cran-through-deducer-0-4-gui-for-r/) does (of course I want to do it in a much much simpler way). 
Basically the application is a GUI for rendering periodical reports that use Sweave .Rnw as some "templating language", but have some frequently changing text.

So ...

1) Is it reasonable to connect it to R / JGR ? or should I just create some stand-alone Java program or Python script that does the job... ?

2) Which part should be written in Java and which in R ? I checked Deducer's source code and found quite a bit of JAVA... which parts would you recommend doing in JAVA ?

3) Can you point me to other packages, and less complex than Deducer that use JGR, so hopefully I can learn from their code?

4) Is there another way to add some menu to the standard R GUI, that would work on "all" OS (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X) ?

Thx for any suggestions, pointers and do-NOT-do-it shouts in adavance!

Comment: Finally ad 1.: I did not want to make this question too specific, but perhaps I should clarify the term "report" for my case a little: it's some periodically comment to some ggplot2 graphs. This comment is non-trivial an cannot be done be any computer. Let's say it's an interpretation of several graphs, explained for a broader public. All I want to do is make these guys (reporters) use R and the easiest thing to do it, is to prevent them from seeing LaTeX code :)

Comment: Don't hide the LaTeX code to users. It's not a good idea, at least make them capable of getting the source if they prefer. People should _"speak"_ LaTeX, like it or not... =)

Comment: You are so right :). People should speak LaTeX and R at least basic HTML and a little SQL... My App just uses LaTeX / .Rnw as a templating language. Templates are edited independently with your favorite LaTeX editor. But if you are just into commenting some graphs you are not supposed to change the Layout and thus you should not be distracted by the options, all you see is text and the invoke pdf creation button :).

Comment: That sounds nice... wish you luck! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For your answer to 4 one can use gWidgetsWWW to create an interactive web page to gather the users input. It can be run on a server with RApache or standalone using the help page web server for R. Here is an example web page. (To run standalone, save this somewhere, say /tmp/test.R, and load with localServerStart("/tmp/test.R")

```
runSweave <- function(...) {
  ## replace with real deal
  ## point is l holds values:
  values <- sapply(l, svalue, simplify=FALSE)
  gmessage(message=sprintf("Run sweave using inputs %s and %s", values$one,values$two), parent=w)
}

runAbout <- function(...) {
  gmessage("A simple GUI for running a report", parent=w)
}

w <- gwindow("Write a report")
l <- list()

actions <- list(run=gaction(label="run",  handler=runSweave, parent=w),
                about=gaction(label="about", handler=runAbout, parent=w))

gmenu(actions, cont=w)

g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
ghtml(boilerplate <- paste("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,",
                           "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                           "Ut enim ad minim",
                           sep="</br>"),
      cont=g)

l$one <- gedit("Enter text here", cont=g)
ghtml(boilerplate, cont=g)
l$two <- gedit("Enter more text here", cont=g)

gstatusbar("thats it...", cont=g)
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to answer the 1<sup>st</sup> and the 4<sup>th</sup> one:

Ad 1. IMHO, it's not "reasonable" to create GUI for Sweave... If I'm writing a report, I'd like to do something like:

```
There were gathered \Sexpr{length(na.omit(x))} valid responses, 
with mean of \Sexpr{mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)} and 
standard deviation \Sexpr{sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)}.

<<qqplot, echo = FALSE, fig = TRUE>>==
qqplot(x)
qqnorm(x)
@
```

[LyX](http://sites.google.com/site/gregorgorjanc/lyx-sweave) already does that (though I use Emacs with ESS and AUCTeX). I mean, you can write a JAVA GUI and facilitate some features... but you must dazzle if you want to get noticed, otherwise, you're destined to invent what's already invented. But you can contribute... just... don't start from scratch without a good reason.

Ad 4. Yes, there is: [RApache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/manual.html) and/or [RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html). You can mash-up R with some nifty JS library (like [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/)) and do something like [Jeroen Ooms](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~jeroen/) did in his [ggplot2](http://www.yeroon.net/ggplot2/)/[stockplot](http://www.jeroenooms.com/stockplot.html)/[lme4](http://rweb.stat.ucla.edu/lme4)/[IRT tool](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~jeroen/irttool.html) application(s). `brew` package is quite useful. There are drawbacks: you need server access, Internet access on the client, but it's cross-platform and server is a beast of a machine, so imagine what it be like to crunch some big data on desktop machine... server/cloud can do it in an eye-blink time.

Since I don't know how to write a single bloody thing in JAVA, HTML/CSS/JavaScript/PHP/MySQL/etc. with R is my weapon of choice.

So there...

Good luck!

Comment: Thx. This is great, I really hope to get several more like this. Here are a few notes: 
- I do not want to revent WYSIWYG for LaTeX, the guys @Lyx done it better, involving JGR was what I wanted to do to prevent starting from scratch
- I do know RApache, brew and Jeroen Ooms fantastic stuff. I did not know RServe and will definitely check it (and also have a closer look to the others again).

Comment: Hell, I think RServe might be exactly what I need.. thx a bunch!

Comment: That's right, RServe has JAVA client... and a client doesn't necessarily have to be a browser! =) Though you can write JAVA applets that will execute in the browser. About Sweave... you can contribute, R definitely needs user-friendly report preparation system.

Comment: I hope I can create something good enough to contribute, but if there's anything where I can finally start to contribute it's at this point.